# Simple jQuery loop & Return the current value

Tags: jquery, dom, loops

I am trying to figure out how to write what I believe is a pretty simple jQuery function, but could use some help.

So I have a var called "linkr" and I am using it like so.

```
$('img#button4').attr('u', linkr);
```

Next, I have an array attached to the linkr

```
var linkr = [
    'button1',
    'button2',
    'button3']
```

I am trying to figure out how to loop through the values in the linkr variable, displaying only one at a time every 5 seconds.

So essentially, the code would represent

```
$('img#button4').attr('u', 'button1');
```

5 seconds later

```
    $('img#button4').attr('u', 'button2');
```

And so on. Thank you in advance for any help or advice that you may offer.

Comment: Don't use invalid attributes. You should use the custom data attribute (`data-*`) instead.

Comment: Yes, I know. but in this case, this code was already put in place by another developer, so I am just trying to work around those pieces. Thanks for the advice though, I will be sure and use the valid data attribute in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var currentIndex = 0; //set this as a global variable i.e. before everything and not inside a function
...
...
setInterval(function(){
    $('img#button4').attr('u', linkr[currentIndex]);
    currentIndex = currentIndex < linkr.length -1 ? currentIndex + 1 : 0;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: @Brock don't use the attribute `u`. It won't validate. For custom attributes use the adequate tool: `data`

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your button swap in a function, and then use `setInterval`

```
var buttonTimer = setInterval(buttonFunction, 5000);

    function buttonFunction() {
      ... your button function
    }

    function abortButtonTimer() { // to be called when you want to stop the timer
      clearInterval(buttonTimer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to set an interval to update button4 then clear it when it goes out of bounds of the array.

```
var iterator = 0;
var timer;

timer = setInterval(function () {
  if (iterator <= linkr.length) {
    $('img#button4').attr('u', linkr[iterator]);
    iterator++;
  }
  else {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Nice, this is super clean. Thank you!

Comment: `attr` `u` ? it's invalid and not to be suggested at all. (ok, depending the runtime.)

Comment: @Brock Just made a few updates. Was using timeout before, but now using interval. Also, forgot to increment iterator. Hopefully that will work now.

Comment: @roXon That's what Brock was asking for. I agree, not ideal. Probably best to store UI related data in your model/script for that button unless it affects display on the page.

Comment: I mean attr `u` set by jQ won't hurt much, but if the DOM is returned from the server full of `u` attributes... someone should not do this job ;)

Comment: I agree. It's not a route I would go.

Answer (score 0):

Use `data` attribute instead of `u` attribute.
 I'll show you how to achieve what you want with the `alt` image attribute:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/apuhug/2/edit)**</kbd>

**All you need:**

```
var c = 0; // a dummy counter :)    
setInterval(function() { 
  $('img#button4').attr('alt', linkr[++c%linkr.length]); // or use 'u' only if REALLY needed
} ,1000 ); // demo only, use 5000 instead
```

Using `data-*` attribute should look like:

```
$('img#button4').data('u', linkr[++c%linkr.length]);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you're looking for, assuming that "sel" is a valid selector, "attr" is a valid attribute for the selector, and "linkr" is a valid array that contains valid values for the "attr":

```
// global vars  - prefixed with "g"
var gidx = 0;
var gsel = "";
var gattr = "";
var glinkr = [];
var gLoopLinkr = null;

// call this function to set up linkr
function LoopLinkr( sel, attr, linkr ){
    gidx = 0; // reset
    gsel = sel;
    gattr = attr;
    glinkr = linkr;
    gLoopLinkr = window.setInterval("DoLoopLinkr", 5000 );
}

function DoLoopLinkr(){
    $(gsel).attr( gatt, linkr[gidx] );
    gidx++;

    // decide how to end this routine ..
    if (gidx=glinkr.length){ 
        // stop doing this
        window.clearInterval( gLoopLinkr );
        // or loop back to the begining and coninue on
        // gidx=0;
    }
}

// e.g. call
LoopLinkr("#mydiv", "background", ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg"] );
```